# Dropbox API v2, InvalidAccessTokenException at attempt to load file after auth

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I've got InvalidAccessTokenException at any attempt to upload file to Dropbox.

For authorization I use next algorithm:

```
Auth.startOAuth2Authentication(context, APP_KEY);

//granting access
//previous activity is reopened

String accessToken = Auth.getOAuth2Token();
DbxRequestConfig requestConfig = DbxRequestConfig.newBuilder(CLIENT_ID)
                    .withHttpRequestor(OkHttp3Requestor.INSTANCE)
                    .build();
DbxClientV2 client = new DbxClientV2(requestConfig, accessToken);
client.files().uploadBuilder(ADDRESS_IN_DROPBOX)
                            .uploadAndFinish(inputStream);
```

which returns InvalidAccessTokenException.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Also maybe Auth.getOAuth2Token() return auth code instead of access code (which is a bit obvious from method name), but how to get access code when auth code is known?

PS I've used Android project as example - https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/tree/master/examples/android and performed auth exactly as in example.

EDIT-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Problem occurs ONLY after revoking access to the app from account settings at Dropbox webpage.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207431186-Android-InvalidAccessTokenException-at-attempt-to-load-file-after-auth- ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found problem in my code.
I've used DropboxClientFactory like in example from Dropbox where client init looks like this

```
public static void init(String accessToken) {
    if (sDbxClient == null)) {
        DbxRequestConfig requestConfig = DbxRequestConfig.newBuilder("ID")
                .withHttpRequestor(OkHttp3Requestor.INSTANCE)
                .build();

        sDbxClient = new DbxClientV2(requestConfig, accessToken);

    }
}
```

And when access token was revoked - init process was not called because sDbxClient is already initialized.

So I added variable accessCode to DropboxClientFactory to hold used access token and now init looks like this

```
public static void init(String accessToken) {
        if (sDbxClient == null || !accessToken.equals(accessCode)) {
            DbxRequestConfig requestConfig = DbxRequestConfig.newBuilder("ID")
                    .withHttpRequestor(OkHttp3Requestor.INSTANCE)
                    .build();

            sDbxClient = new DbxClientV2(requestConfig, accessToken);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You noted:

> Problem occurs ONLY after revoking access to the app from account settings at Dropbox webpage.

In that case, this [InvalidAccessTokenException](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.0.x/com/dropbox/core/InvalidAccessTokenException.html) is expected. If a user revokes the token, e.g., by unlinking the app via https://www.dropbox.com/account/security , any further API calls attempted with that token will fail with this exception. You should have your code catch this exception and prompt the user to re-link the app if they want to continue using it.

Comment: I've done so.
Catched exception and started authorization process again.
But after attempt to upload file right after authorization there are another InvalidAccessTokenException.